# Backup MX record with same public IP?

Tags: email

I have two Mac Mini's - both provide redundant DNS and Open Directory services. I want to use Mail service so that everything is integrated with my user accounts.

Unfortunately I only have one public IP address. Is it possible to make my second Mac a backup MX server? I would basically have the public DNS of my domain MX record point to the public static IP. Could I then use internal DNS to setup a backup email server? If I add two IP's to the same mx.example.com then mail could potentially round-robin which I don't want. I need mail to always go to primary server first, then if down, go to the second.

This is for personal home use. I know its not best practice but I'm also not spending $30-50 a month for backup mx service. I just want something to prevent losing mail if I upgrade/replace the primary machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup isn't clear: if these are home servers, isn't there a router routing all mail requests to one of your servers?

Still, to (partially) provide an answer to your question, in your situation, you shouldn't worry about losing email: according to [RFC 2821](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), section 4.5.4.1 about Sending Strategy:

> Retries continue until the message is transmitted or the sender gives
>      up; the give-up time generally needs to be at least 4-5 days. […]

[RFC 5321](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt) adds:

> It MAY
>      be appropriate to set a shorter maximum number of retries for non-
>      delivery notifications and equivalent error messages than for
>      standard messages.

So you should have 4 days before losing your email. Then, if you're using a router, you could just make it route incoming traffic to email port to the backup MX server in case you need to do maintenance work on the primary one.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Port forwarding is going to my primary server. I forgot about that. I guess I could port forward to the backup during maintenance. If there is unexpected downtime, I can log in remotely as long as my network is up to change it on the router.  Thanks!